# Trouble Understanding Objects and Modifying Variables of them in Linked List in Java

Tags: java, object, variables, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

As the title implies, I trying to implement a doubly linked list in java.

However while working on it I came across something I have trouble understanding.

For context here is my code:

```
public class Doublelist{ 
    Node head; 
    public static class Node{   
        private int data;
        private Node prev; 
        private Node next = null; 
        public Node (int data){
            this.data = data;  
            prev = null;
            next = null; //default case for new node
        }   
        public String toString(){  
            String i = Integer.toString(data);
            return i;
        }    

//Method below handles inputting data at end of the linked list
    public static Doublelist add_node_end(Doublelist list, int data){  
        Node add_node = new Node(data);  
        add_node.next = null; 
        if (list.head == null){ 
            list.head = add_node;  
            list.head.prev = null;  
        } 
        else{  
            Node travel = list.head;    
            while (travel.next != null){   
                travel = travel.next; 
            }      
           add_node.prev = travel;
           travel.next = add_node;   
        }
        return list;
    }  


    public static void modify_obj_test (Doublelist list){  
        Node travel  = list.head;     
        System.out.println("Travel initially: "+ travel); 
        Node currnode = travel;  
        travel.next.next = null;
        System.out.println("Travel.next.next: "+ travel.next.next);  
        System.out.println("Currnode.next.next: "+ currnode.next.next); 

    }

    }
```

HERE is the method that shows the issue I am having: 
*(Note: I created this method just to show the trouble in my understanding, doesn't do anything for the linked list )*

```
    public static void modify_obj_test (Doublelist list){  
        Node travel  = list.head;     
        System.out.println("Travel initially: "+ travel); 
        Node currnode = travel;  
        travel.next.next = null;
        System.out.println("Travel.next.next: "+ travel.next.next);  
        System.out.println("Currnode.next.next: "+ currnode.next.next); 

    }
```

The output of this gives the following

```
Travel initially: 1
Travel.next.next: null
Currnode.next.next: null
```

However when I change this function and I do the following

```
    public static void modify_obj_test (Doublelist list){  
        Node travel  = list.head;     
        System.out.println("Travel initially: "+ travel); 
        Node currnode = travel;   
        travel = travel.next; 
        travel = travel.next; 
        travel = null;
        System.out.println("Travel.next.next: "+ travel);  
        System.out.println("Currnode.next.next: "+ currnode.next.next); 
    }
```

The output then becomes

```
Travel initially: 1
Travel.next.next: null
Currnode.next.next: 3
```

My question is,  why is it that the currnode.next.next is being modified when I make travel.next.next = null, however when I shift down the list one by one by doing travel = travel.next, 
It doesn't effect the currnode variable?

I thought that by making currnode = travel, was sorta like making a temp variable in C where a copy of the value is kept safe while an operation goes on, I didn't realize that depending on how I modify the travel variable it can also affect the currnode variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it that the currnode.next.next is being modified when I make travel.next.next = null

If you are referring to the fist set of code, `currnode` is pointing to the same list as `travel` (`list.head`) and since you set `travel.next.next` to null, `currnode.next.next` is also null (since they are both pointing to the same list).

```
travel.next.next = null;
```

The above line changes the data in the list.

> however when I shift down the list one by one by doing travel =
>   travel.next, It doesn't effect the currnode variable?

In the second set of code, you are not setting `travel.next.next` to null.  You are setting `travel` null.  So, `travel` no longer points to anything and and you have not modified the list whatsoever.

```
travel = travel.next;  // Move 'travel' to the next node
travel = travel.next;  // Move 'travel' to the next node
travel = null;  // Set 'travel' so that it is pointing to nothing
```

None of the above lines change the data in the list.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. I kinda knew that something was being done, to the travel variable , when travel = travel.next as opposed to travel.next.next, but I just couldn't articulate or understand what exactly was going on. Again thank you!